# Buffering using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I did multiple ring buffer in ArcMap but I need to divide it to 8 equal parts not separated, each part 45 degree

How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you really using ArcMap 10.0 to try and do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with with the [military tools geoprocessing toolbox](https://github.com/Esri/military-tools-geoprocessing-toolbox) and the range rings tools. Where you set the number of radials to 8.